# Column value conditional on previous value in a dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe "bd" that looks like this:

```
    Unnamed: 0  timestamp   open    high    low close   volume  close_time  quote_av    trades  tb_base_av  tb_quote_av ignore  Ticker  log
0   0   17/04/2018  0.01000 0.02500 0.01000 0.02056 10026646.20 1.524010e+12    212822.90450    14612   3080879.33  65362.06898 0.0 ADABNB  0.720762
1   1   18/04/2018  0.02061 0.02227 0.02050 0.02131 6150235.16  1.524100e+12    131540.20910    8736    2932444.56  62649.93292 0.0 ADABNB  0.033400
2   2   19/04/2018  0.02126 0.02239 0.02125 0.02182 4029868.44  1.524180e+12    87958.85789 6894    1975139.34  43153.92312 0.0 ADABNB  0.026000
3   3   20/04/2018  0.02180 0.02429 0.02171 0.02400 4082134.58  1.524270e+12    94989.57750 7674    1489298.21  34675.98730 0.0 ADABNB  0.096144
4   4   21/04/2018  0.02400 0.02494 0.02031 0.02145 6363706.18  1.524360e+12    138161.60430    7733    3469179.07  74832.05245 0.0 ADABNB  -0.112329
```

I want the "Next Day" column to only be equal to log(-1) so the next day's log returns, if the Ticker Column is the same for both days. I tried creating a new column like this:

```
bd['Next Day'] = np.where(bd['Ticker'] == bd[['Ticker'](-1)], bd['log'].shift(-1))
```

I also tried the following:

```
bd['ND2'] = bd['Next Day'].apply(lambda x: bd['Next Day'] if bd['Ticker'] == bd['Ticker'](-1) else '')
```

But I get an error "list" object is not callable. Or "series" object is not callable in the second case

Thank you.

Comment: could you please add data here...? @Klakteuh

Comment: try `bd.loc[bd['Ticker'].eq(bd['Ticker'].shift(-1)), 'Next Day'] = bd['log'].shift(-1)`, I think you want `bd['Ticker'].shift(-1)` not `bd[['Ticker'](-1)]`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.